# Using group filter in template from view results

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a `user.group.filter` result returning `True` in a Django view.

On my index page, I want to restrict content based on the users group. I've done this using the following:

views.py

```
def index(request):
    template_name = "index/index.html"
    is_teamleader = request.user.groups.filter(name='TL').exists()
    is_employee = request.user.groups.filter(name='Employee').exists()
    context = {}
    return render_to_response(template_name, request, RequestContext(request))
```

and then used the following in my index.html page:

```
{% if is_teamleader %}
    <div id="side">
      <div id="sticky-sidebar">
        <h2> Links</h2>
        <div id="sidecontent2" class="cf"><a href="/Form"><span>Form</span></a>
        </div>
      <!-- <div id="sidecontent3" class="cf"><span>Sticky Widget</span></div> -->
      </div>
    </div>
{% elif is_employee %}
    <div id="side">
      <div id="sticky-sidebar">
        <h2> Links</h2>
        <div id="sidecontent"><span>Youre an Employee!</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
{% else %}
    <div id="side">
      <div id="sticky-sidebar">
        <h2> Links</h2>
        <div id="sidecontent"><span>No Link Access</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

Despite the changes I make, this results in the 'else' statement no matter what group the user is in.

Do I need to add something to the `render_to_response` to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forgot to render the context

you need:

```
def index(request):
    template_name = "index/index.html"
    is_teamleader = request.user.groups.filter(name='TL').exists()
    is_employee = request.user.groups.filter(name='Employee').exists()
    context = {
       'is_teamleader': is_teamleader,
       'is_employee': is_employee
    }
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

Comment: I'm really mad at myself for not realising this. Thank you. Works perfectly.